# How to call JavaScript method on load from Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, onload

I'd like to know how I can trigger isLoaded() as soon as my .swf movie is loaded.

```
  function isLoaded(){
     alert("Loaded");
  }

  my movie.swf loaded via SWFObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Also if you want it to be called once your SWF has been fully loaded, just do this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
function _handle(e:Event):void
{
    if(root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded >= root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
        // Do ExternalInterface.call()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I use. It doesn't solve my problem of executing my js on load.

Comment: Well your ExternalInterface call won't happen until the SWF has loaded. If you want to be more precise you could call it at the completion of a pre-loader.

Comment: this actually didn't fix the problem. The strange thing is that it works in Chrome but not FF or IE

Comment: Take a look at the browser support of ExternalInterface on the link in my answer.